# How can i make sure i make something happen in php at a certain time, and it happens at that time for everyone's time zone?

Tags: php, date, time, timezone

i have read many different sites and many different solutions that deal with timezones and server times and client/user local time, etc., but no one explains in detail this exact situation i'm trying to accomplish.

i have this php code that makes something expire at a certain date and time, and it works great, but it only makes the content expire at the server's time.  i want it to expire on all time zones when that time comes for that time zone.  i don't want the content to expire at the same time for all time zones.

so let's say i want something to expire at 2pm, the very first timezone that hits 2pm they shouldn't be able to see the expired content, but the rest of the time zones should still be able to see it.  then when the 2nd timezone hits 2pm, that timezone shouldn't see the content.  so now 2 timezones can't see the content but the rest of the time zones should still see it.  and this continues one timezone at a time until all the timezones have hit 2pm.

please tell me how to adjust this php to make the above happen.

```
<?php
$end_date = strtotime('02:00pm April 1, 2012');
$now = time();
if ($end_date < $now) {
?>
different content to display after date and time has arrived,
or don't put anything here if you just want expired content to disappear
and nothing else to take it's place.
<?php } else { ?>
content to display while the date and time hasn't arrived yet.
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems? Determining the user's timezone?

Comment: You could use javascript to get the time, and pass it to the server using AJAX. Or if all users are signed up, have them pick their GMT time, and add or subtract that amount from GMT.

Comment: i guess so.  i want a staggering timezone code, if that's a possibility, meaning i don't want my time zone or California's time zone.  i want all time zones.

Comment: it's not a sign up type site.  basically something should occur at user's local time, and it shouldn't affect the rest of the timezones.

Comment: hello everyone.  i got very close with this i found...
http://www.mtdev.com/2002/07/display-local-time

but then after local time has been set, my original code above still grabs the server time for it's calculation.  how can i modify the above php code so that the $now variable gets populated with the local time that has been set?

Answer (score 0):

What you require is a `<select>User please select your timezone</select>` (all the way until +12 <> -12, and that option should select EVERY user which lands on your site - including you - for something like that to happen.

Server have no idea per IP - which user is in which zone, unless you work it out somehow.

You should work with GMT time, and develop special function for handling user (timezone) inputs for that to happen.

Comment: You would need a select box all the way up to UTC+14, to keep the people in Kiribati happy. And if you do that, a several people will enter that time, just because they can.

Comment: Actually Im on my way doing that thing soon and if someone wants to be in Kiribati just by clicking select on a website, hey pleasure is all mine :D

Comment: Then you would probably also know that there are about 40 different times in use, and if you want the user to select a named time zone, the list will be much longer.

Comment: Not really so. I intend to do only from GMT+12 to GMT-12 in "per hour" manner what is 24 options. Maybe just a few with X:30. Without mentioning cities.

Comment: You should also add GMT+13 and GMT+14, because they are in use too (and it fits in your per hour offset).